# The FlipClock .getTime() does not work? Does not update return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, flipclock

I asked a similar question but did not receive. So I'll re word it. Why doesn't the flipClock function getTime() return a value for each time the clock face changes? When I output this to the console, the value is an always remains at 10. It never counts down. The clock however works perfectly fine. How do I get the current time of the clock?

```
var clock;

  // Instantiate a counter
  clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), 10, {
    clockFace: 'MinuteCounter',
    autoStart: false,
    countdown: true
  });

if(clock.getTime() == 0){
   //Redirect to another page
   window.location.href = "example.html";
}else{
 console.log("This is the time now" + getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you call it once, It need to bind to `interval` event. create it in callback function

```js
var clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), 10, {
  clockFace: 'MinuteCounter',
  autoStart: true,
  countdown: true,
  callbacks: {
    interval: function() {
      var time = this.factory.getTime().time;
      console.clear()
      console.log("Countdown now: " + time);
      if (time == 0) {
        alert('Countdown finished!');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.clock{margin-top:30px}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.js"></script>


<div class="clock"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I've misunderstood your question. If this answer is way off the mark and patronising, I apologise.

The code you provided will only execute once. Immediately after creating the clock, you call `clock.getTime()`. The result will be 10 at that instant. Consequently your redirect code will not execute (as the result did not equal 0), and you will immediately fall through to the code inside your `else` block. That code will log out the clock's current time to the console (which will still be 10 because the code executed so quickly).

In order to observe the clock counting down, you will need to repeatedly call `clock.getTime()`. You should read up on the concept of polling. You may find `setInterval` useful (see https://alligator.io/js/settimeout-setinterval/).